# Bluetooth Device Tracker/ Finder

Tags: bluetooth, gps, tracking

I lost my Bluetooth earphones and had been searching for it recently. I would like to ask if there are any programs (or how I can code my own) that can help look for a paired but not connected Bluetooth device. Thanks in advance and much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Any app can find your bluetooth earphones, only if it is ON. From my perspective, one suggestion is to [save the name or device address]remove pairing from your phone for the headset and do a bluetooth search . If your headset appears on the device discovery list, then it should be around.